# Limit uses of a function in a period of time (android)

Tags: java, android, time

I want to limit the calls to a function within one day.
The problem is I'm a bit confused of how to use the `Date` and `Calendar` classes...

```
private int usesLeft //Set every day to the number of uses
private void function() {
    if(usesLeft > 0) {
        //Function's body...
    }
    usesLeft--;
}
```

I need to find out when a new day starts in order to reset the `usesLeft` variable.

Comment: So when I set my clock +24h I may use that cool function again?

Comment: whos running this method ? the user or the system ?

Comment: The system, when a user triggers an event.

Comment: As zapl mentioned, if you need this to be secure from user tampering, then you'll have to manage it on a server.

Comment: Yeah, but I need something to start with...

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution...
The better side of this solution is that the user can't "cheat" because then he'll lose activity days (If my analysis of the code behavior is right).

```
if(lastDayActive < (int)Math.floor(System.currentTimeMillis()/86400000)) {
    usesLeft = 100;
    //Initializes the day value
    lastDayActive = (int)Math.floor(System.currentTimeMillis()/86400000);
}
```

If there's any way to prevent the user from manually changing the date and therefore gaining more uses I'd really like to hear about it.